# improving a* search for finding path in a triangulated environment

Tags: algorithm, math, artificial-intelligence, computational-geometry

I have an area which is represented by constrained delaunay triangulations. I am playing around with the problem of finding a path among two points. I am using the paper provided by Marcelo Kallmann as a reference point to approach this problem. However, instead of using the Chazelle funnel algorithm as proposed by Kallmann [paper link](http://graphics.ucmerced.edu/publications/2005_IJCAI_Kallmann.pdf), I am planning to use the A* search algorithm which plans the path in a grid environment pretty efficiently.

For the heuristic cost function, I am using the Euclidean distance from the current node to the goal node and for selecting the neighbor nodes, I am drawing a line segment from the current point p to the mid-point of the edge of triangle. [This idea was proposed by kallmann] The cost to a neighbor node is also given by the Euclidean distance among them.

Here is the figure from the Kallmann demonstrating the use of the mid-point of the edge technique to generate various paths to the triangle containing the goal node.

[image: Visibility Graphs]

Now this technique works fine when the triangle density is not large enough in an area. But say if the generated triangulation for a set of points looks like this [image: 500-pt triangulation]

I was wondering whether there is a way to improve the efficiency of the algorithm by using some other technique like IDA* or ID-DFS? A Triangulation Reduction A* (TRA*) has been proposed,but I could not understand it since it was too formally defined. The details of the TRA* method can be found in section 5 of this [thesis](http://skatgame.net/mburo/ps/thesis_demyen_2006.pdf) by Demyen.

I would appreciate some thoughts on it. If some code is required to be shared, I will edit this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the ID algorithms trade off the cost of bookkeeping incurred by A* by repeating work, thus potentially making them slower (but hopefully not much slower).  So what measure you're trying to improve the efficiency of will affect how useful these will be.

Comment: Scott, the measure I am using is the algorithm giving me a path in say 3 mins in the triangulation described above. Because if I use a* search, it takes ages to compute the path.